# Fragment getArgument() right location

Tags: android, android-fragments

Playing around with `Fragments`, I came to wonder about the right way to populate my fragments.

As the doc says, I use the `newInstance()` pattern to add arguments to my fragments :

```
public static ItemFragment newInstance(ItemRealm item, AnnaleModel model) {
    ItemFragment fragment = new ItemFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(MyPagerAdapter.KEY_ITEM, item.getId());
    args.putParcelable(MyPagerAdapter.KEY_MODEL, model);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

But then, there is several behaviours I can see happening on the net.

The most seen it to put `getArguments()` in the `onCreateView()` method and put the results in fields :

```
protected String itemId;
protected Model mModel ;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args == null || (!args.containsKey(MyPagerAdapter.KEY_ITEM) || !args.containsKey(MyPagerAdapter.KEY_MODEL))) {
        Log.e("TAG", "incorrect Bundle");
        return null;
    }
    itemId = args.getString(MyPagerAdapter.KEY_ITEM);
    mModel = args.getParcelable(MyPagerAdapter.KEY_MODEL);
}
```

I can see on some other places to put the same exact thing in the `Fragment.onCreate()` method instead of `onCreateView()`.

And the last behaviour is to call `getArguments()` in the getter.

```
private Model getModel(){
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        return getArguments().getParcelable(AnnalePagerAdapter.KEY_MODEL);
    }
    Log.e("Dan", "ItemFragment :: getModel (279): model==null !!");
    return null;
}//I can also think about some lazyloading is needed
```

The questions are then :

- Is there now a consensus on which pattern to use (these 3 or even another) ?
- Is there some contexts I should rather use one than another ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a getter. That just complicates things imo. Why include fragment logic in the the `Model` class, right?

As for `onCreateView()` vs `onCreate()`, I call `getArguments()` in `onCreate()` because this method is called before the view is created. So, if you have any calculations or other stuff then you can do it here. Save it in global vars and set them in `onCreateView`. But instead of doing that, you can just do it in `onCreateView`, right? So what's the difference then? It helps to keep the logic separated. Initialize/update the view in `onCreateView` and do pre-calculations stuff in `onCreate`

[Example from google's samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/analytics/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/analytics/ImageFragment.java)